# How to replace the 1st match block of text with sed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, sh

I am trying to replace the 1st match block of text with sed. 
Consider this example.

```
read -r -d '' VAR <<"EOF"
<Button3d
some text
some text
/>

<Button3d
some text
some text
/>
EOF

sed '1,/^<Button3d/,/^\/>/c {
</Button\
different text\
different text\
/>\
}' <<< $VAR
```

But with GNU sed I get the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown command: `,'

Expected output should be:

```
<Button
different text
different text
/>

<Button3d
some text
some text
/>
```

Some have suggested using an XML parser, however that would be a complete overkill for this simple example.

Comment: This looks like XML. You should use an XML parser.

Comment: Updated. I am not parsing complicated XML.

Comment: @user11316197 when using regex in sed always use `sed 's+regex+new-text+g' file.txt` and use `g` only when you want to replace all the occurrences otherwise just remove it. `+` separator should be used with regex rather than `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `sed` supports `-z`, you can use something like

```
sed -z 's#/>#\r#g; s/<Button3d[^\r]*\r//; s#\r#/>#g' <<< "${VAR}"
```

EDIT:
Other text can be inserted with

```
sed -z 's#/>#\r#g; s/<Button3d[^\r]*\r/<Button3d\nOther text\nSecond line\n\r/; s#\r#/>#g' <<< "${VAR}"
```

Comment: Hmm. What are you replacing it with??

Comment: Since '`#<Button3d.*/>##` will replace as much as possible, you need a trick telling to replace until the first occurance of `/>`. The trick used is first replacing this string to an unique single character (like the windows carriage return), do the replace and resore the other strings back to `/>`.

Comment: This just removes it. It has to replace the entire block with other text.

Comment: Answer edited. Using a var with a replacement string  is more complicated.

Comment: Where do you specify the match number 1st, 2nd or 3rd??

Comment: Second with the `2` in `sed -z 's#/>#\r#g; s/<Button3d[^\r]*\r/<Button3d\nOther text\nSecond line\n\r/2; s#\r#/>#g'`